# resizing fancybox iframe. having problems!

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fancybox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.microsite').live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
      href: $(this).attr('href'),
      type: 'iframe',
      width: '110%',
      height: '110%',
      autoDimensions : false,
      autoscale : 'false'
    })
    return false;
});
```

I am trying to eliminate horizontal scrollbars.  I cannot edit the contents of the iframe itself.  I want to resize the iframe, but it seems that it cannot be larger than 100%.  anyone have any ideas?  I simply cannot get this thing to open wider.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it`s because you have passed autoscale as string, try changing `autoscale : 'false'` to `autoscale : false`